# Generator Function Needed when State is Irrelevant?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, iterable

In the below example, a `generator` function is used to produce a unique ID.

The code snippet comes from the following medium post: [Source](https://codeburst.io/javascript-generator-yield-next-async-await-e428b0cb52e4)

```js
function* UUIDGenerator() {
  let d, r;
  while (true) {
    yield 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      r = (new Date().getTime() + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
      d = Math.floor(d / 16);
      return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
  }
};

let myGen = UUIDGenerator();

console.log(myGen.next());
```

**QUESTION 1**

What is the point of using a `generator` in that snippet? The code does not need to remember any state between each invocation. Therefore, can't we just as well use a normal function object?

**QUESTION 2**

`Iterables` (like `generators`) are only needed when we need an `iterator object` in order to iterate over a sequence, remembering state between each invocation? If we do not need to remember state, an `iterable` is not necessary right?

**QUESTION 3**

Side question: `ESLint` complains when using functions inside loops. Such a pattern is highly typical in `generators`, as seen. How is this most commonly solved?

```js
function UUIDGenerator() {
  let d, r;
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    let r = (new Date().getTime() + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    let d = Math.floor(d / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
  });
};

console.log(UUIDGenerator());
```

Comment: My guess would be that they wanted to use the generator API and didn't want to write a `.next()` method on an empty object. This is a strange implementation though. The first time it is run, `d` will be NaN since `Math.floor( undefined / 16 )` equals NaN. But since `d` is not used anywhere, that error does not throw anything. So my second idea would be that in the past, `d` was used somewhere to calculate the next UUID, and hence, the generator makes sense. As you notice from the comments, it's just a bad article.

Comment: Please ask a single question per post.

Comment: I don't get your second question. An iterable is necessary when you want to iterate it, like in a `for … of`loop. If you don't want to iterate it, it doesn't need to be iterable. This has nothing to do with whether the iteration has state or not (your first question), although stateless iteration is either empty or infinite.

Comment: Also, I would suggest you look somewhere else on learning this stuff,  eg.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Comment: @Keith I have gone throught MDN and a few other sources, so grasp the `iterable/iterator protocols` and `generator` concepts decently well. I just didn't get why he would use a `generator` in the shown snippet. I see that both `r` and `d` states are saved across the iteration, but `r`s previous value is not used at all, and I am not sure what the point of saving `d`s state is.

Comment: @Bergi sure thing, good feedback regarding multiple questions. Regarding your second comment, my second question is: Let's say I want to call a function multiple times. I can create a generator function and iterate over it manually with next(), creating new values on demand, or I can just call a regular function multiple times. If I do not need to remember state between each invocation, I might as well do the latter, right?  I'll try to clarify the post.

Comment: @Magnus That is the point, it's pointless.  So you are correct, and that website link is a total waste of time.  So not really anything to get or understand.  But the fact you spotted this oddity, is actually a good sign.. :)

Comment: `I might as well do the latter, right?`  There is nothing stopping you creating an iterator  for something that doesn't have stored state, you could create one that emits the current date / time for example, and place inside a `for of`

Comment: @Magnus That sounds exactly like the first question - yes you can just use a normal function. (Notice that even normal functions can remember state between their calls, in closure or on an object). *Iterables* are just a convenience and a convention.

Comment: @Keith and @Bergi , got it, thanks a lot both of you! Keith, yep I understand that state is not required for `iteration objects` in any way. But I guess it isn't much of a point without saving state. In your example Keith, I could just create a regular `for` loop that outputted the date. I might be missing something, but I can't imagine a case where I would rather create that into an `iteration object` and iterate over it.

Comment: `I might be missing something`  I think @Bergi said it nicely, `a convenience and a convention`.. Going back to the date time part, `for (date of dates) { console.log(date); await sleep(1000); }`  For some might just look nicer than, `while (true) { let date = getDate(); console.log(date); await sleep(1000); }`